# Keyboard layout do not fit

Tags: 13.10, dell, keyboard-layout, settings

I have a problem with Keyboard layout on Ubuntu 13.10.

My regional settings are italian and also the keyboard seems (in the settings menu is selected italian one) but when I digit special button I discover is english setted.

It happened sometimes (I do not understand when) when I restart the pc.

My notebook is a dell 640m.

Comment: I am not so able with Ubuntu, how can I check it?

Comment: In what application/program did you notice the problem?

Comment: eg> when I type my email address (I find : instead of @), or when I write here ">(" (should be the smile)

Comment: It happened also in text file like LibreOffice (I am using Chrome browser)

Answer (score 1):

All what you have to do is to remove the English language tab from your keyaboard settings (Layout tab)

Comment: I have removed it by click on "-" in the settings but it always works on English layout

Comment: Go back there: you will find it, delete it again, and close the keyboard window. It sounds strange, but I faced the same problem as yours.

Comment: After the removing the English option is gone...

Comment: Nice you get rid of it. Please accept my answer by clicking on the small round button below where you voted for my answer :)

Comment: I was not clear: I have removed English language (so there is only italian option keyboard), but the problem is not solved at all